# Some problems with template

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

```
template<class TypeIterator>
void Generate(const TypeIterator& first, const TypeIterator& last)
{
    //do something
}
```

When I tried to call the generate function like this:

```
PhanSo arr[10];
Generate(arr, arr+10);
```

I got the error message: *void Generate(const TypeIterator &,const TypeIterator &)' : template parameter 'TypeIterator' is ambiguous*

When I used:

```
PhanSo arr[10];
Generate(&arr[0], &arr[10]);
```

Then my program built succeeded.

I tried to fix it by removing "&" in the function parameter

```
template<class TypeIterator>
void Generate(const TypeIterator first, const TypeIterator last);
```

Then there is no error.
Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: As a side note, you're trying to access beyond the bounds of your array: `arr[10]`. The last valid index is at `arr[9]`.

Comment: @user2079303 `arr + 10` is perfectly legal because you can use a 1-past-the-end iterator as long as you don't dereference it. `arr[10]` invokes UB though.

Comment: `arr+10` can be used as an iterator to **one past the last element in the array** so as long as you do not de-reference you'll be fine.
Example: `while(ptr != last)` where last is pointing to `arr+10`

Comment: Ah yes, ofcourse. I fixed the comment.

Comment: @user2079303 Sorry to bother you again, but no one is trying to access `arr[10]` at all as of right now.

Comment: @Nard `Generate(&arr[0], &arr[10]);` does. I'm just pointing out that it's not agood workaround.

Comment: @user2079303 Thanks. Now I see where you're concerned about and I think that you had a good point. It seemed perfectly fine to me because of the `&` operator but the `[]` operator does have a higher precedence.


However, I've just tried printing `arr[10000000]` and `&arr[10000000]`. `arr[10000000]` results in a segmentation fault, but `&arr[10000000]` seems to simply perform an offset of 10000000 from the address of `arr`.

Just as the expression `arr[10000000];` alone will not cause your program to crash, everything is fine until you use the value for something.

Answer (score 1):

**An array is not a pointer.** An array's name being used as a pointer to the first element of the array is merely **syntactic sugarcoating**.

> When the **template parameter** is a **reference** type,
>   array-to-pointer conversions will not happen.

When you had `void Generate(const TypeIterator& first, const TypeIterator& last)` called with `Generate(arr, arr+10);`, `arr` resolves to `PhanSo[10]` while `arr+10` resolves to a `PhanSo*`, which was actually pointed out by both G++ and Microsoft compilers as ambiguity.

When you had `void Generate(const TypeIterator& first, const TypeIterator& last)` called with `Generate(&arr[0], &arr[10]);`, things became much clearer for the compiler because you are specifically supplying the **address** of the elements to the function, therefore TypeIterator resolves to `PhanSo*`.

Finally, when you had `void Generate(const TypeIterator first, const TypeIterator last)` called with `Generate(arr, arr+10);`, since the **template parameter** is no longer a **reference** type, normal array-to-pointer conversion occurs and `TypeIterator` resolves to `PhanSo*`.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: No problem. I'm really glad it helped you. I was merely taught well by my teachers.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Generate(arr, arr+10);`

- `first` would be `const PhanSo (&)[10]`.
- but `second` decayed to pointer : `const PhanSo *`.

and so the type mismatch.

As array cannot be passed by value `arr` decay too to pointer when you have

```
template<class TypeIterator>
void Generate(const TypeIterator first, const TypeIterator last);
```

without reference.